# Are function scope static or thread_local variables initialized in first entry in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, lazy-initialization, thread-local

In C++11 the initialization of function scope static/thread_local variables are guaranteed to be thread safe. Are they also guaranteed to be initialized on function entry?

Answer (score 0):

According to [stmt.dcl]/4 (emphasis mine):

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage
>   duration (3.7.2) is performed **before any other initialization takes place.** Constant initialization (3.6.2) of a
>   block-scope entity with static storage duration, if applicable, is performed **before its block is first entered.**
>   An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of other block-scope variables with static or
>   thread storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is permitted to statically initialize
>   a variable with static or thread storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). Otherwise such a variable is
>   initialized **the first time control passes through its declaration;** such a variable is considered initialized upon
>   the completion of its initialization.

I'm not sure what you mean by "on function entry", but the answers are all in the paragraph I quoted.

Comment: What I mean is that if I do not call the function, the constructors should never be called.

Comment: @SiyuanRen I believe that that is not guaranteed since the paragraph says that early initialization is allowed. If this matters for a specific purpose you have in mind, I suggest posting a new question that illustrates the case you are concerned about.